# why is sizeof(str.substr(0,3).c_str()) giving me 8?

Tags: c++, string

```
string str = "abcdefgdcb";

cout << sizeof(str.substr(0,3).c_str());
```

For some reason, the above string is giving me 8. I assumed c_str() returns a null string, and sizeof uses the null to determine the size of the string.

Comment: You mean a "null-terminated string". (A "null string" would be something entirely different.)

Comment: @james: What he actually means is a NUL-terminated string.

Comment: @user52343 you should really accept one of the answers...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because `sizeof` doesn't give you the length of a string, it gives you the size of the type (`const char *` in this case).  Try `strlen`.

Answer (score 4):

`c_str` returns a `const char *`. On your system, `sizeof (const char *) == 8`, like any other pointer.

Answer (score 2):

8 is the size of a pointer on your machine (64-bit), that's what c_str() returns.

Use strlen to get the length of the string.

Answer (score 2):

> I assumed ... sizeof uses the null to determine the size of the string.

There's your problem.  `sizeof` tells you the size of a variable, which has nothing to do with the value inside the variable, ever.

Comment: @ColeJohnson: This is a C++ question.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I am aware of that